# Can we open a binary file in C without fopen?

Tags: c, binary, fopen

In C programming, can we open a binary file without fopen() , only with open ?
Because I need a file descriptor, not a filestream.

Thank you

Comment: On POSIX systems, like Linux and OSX, the C standard I/O function (like `fopen` and `fread` etc.) are most likely using the lower level system calls like `open` and `read`. In fact you can get the descriptor from any `FILE` using the [`fileno`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fileno.html) function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, use

```
int file;
file = open("yourfile.txt", O_RDONLY | O_BINARY, 0); //change flags if necessary
```

use these includes:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h> //for the open() permission flags
```

The `file` variable  is used to refer to the file. If un- successful, open() returns -1.

See other file handling functions [here](http://gd.tuwien.ac.at/languages/c/programming-bbrown/c_075.htm)

Comment: But if I add this flag on a regular file, does it work ? Because i can't determine if a file a binary or not

Comment: @RomanGrout The only important difference between text and binary is end on line character AFAIK, so you should not worry much about it.

Comment: Hey ! It seems doesnt work :)
" error: ‘O_BINARY’ undeclared (first use in this function) "

Comment: Yes it would work, because you can read any file in binary. Every filetype contains binary data, but the way you see it depends on the extension. i.e. a .txt file is binary data but represented as ASCII or Unicode characters

Comment: @RomanGrout  there is no `O_BINARY` flag because `open()` doesn't care about end of line character so a `O_BINARY` flag doesn't make sense.

Comment: @iharob Ok, so i try to open a binary, read in it and pass it thought a socket in C, so in "download" my binary in a other process and write it in a file (myFTP project for school :) )    When i try to read a jpg or execute a binary the file is corrupted and regular file are well. I precise i am on Ubuntu

Comment: @RomanGrout it sounds like it has nothing to do with `open()` or `fopen()` but instead `read()` and where you are reading to...

Comment: Yes, i do that and it works for text file, but in case of binary file the file is corrupted :(

Comment: @moffeltje I read to a char[1024] which is in a "tcp packet" structure that i pass in my socket to my server/client

Comment: I think your problems are at the writing end, not reading end. Make sure you write your files as "binary". Otherwise, if you write on Windows, any occurence of byte 10 will be replaced with pair of 10, 13.

Comment: @RomanGrout: O_BINARY is a Windows thing. If you want to support it in your code, you can `#define` it to 0 if it isn't defined and include it in the `open` options. POSIX guarantees that there is no difference between binary and text mode.

Comment: @mafso So when i passe a 1.5 mo .txt file in my_ftp binary it works well and wen i pass a pdf, jpg  .. it is corrupted :(. I try a diff terminal command it say files differ

Comment: @RomanGrout: I don't understand, I'm afraid. Outside Windows, opening in text or binary mode doesn't make any difference; and in Windows, `O_BINARY` should be defined. What platform are you using?

Comment: In am in Elementary OS, a fork of Ubuntu in x64. I do not put manually a '\0' or an EOF, maybe it is this ?

Comment: @RomanGrout I think my answer answered your question, so you can mark it as accepted if it did :)

Comment: @RomanGrout [use the @-notation to have users notified], I can't tell without knowing what you do, and it doesn't really seem to be part of your question.